# How to ignore JSON data when posting through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Actually my JSON data as an object i am sending through AJAX is:

```
{
  plotId: "668",
  geogPhysZone: "4",
  districtCode: "4",
  posMethod: "1",
  sRS: "45",
  crewLeader: "",
  date: "",
  distanceToOtherLanduse: "",
  distanceToSettlement: ""
}
```

But the value, which are going `null` from JSON is not available in my table column while posting, so I am getting 500 (Internal Server Error). So while sending from AJAX I want to ignore the value which are null.

My code is called when button is clicked:

```
$("#generalSubmitButton").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = Object.assign($("#generalForm1").toObject(), $("#headForm").toObject());

  console.log(form_data);

  $.ajax({
    url: A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/plot-general/save",
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
    success: function() {
      alert("Successful");
    },
    error: function(response) {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 409:
          alert("error");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This handling must be done at server side. (By removing validations)

Comment: For a more robust solution it's probably better to validate the data server-side if you can. You shouldn't be throwing 500 errors.

Comment: form data should be sent in ajax as it is generated. Handle at your backend to ignore the null key-values and work on available values

Comment: i could have done in server side but the datatype are not available in model package and i cant add these datatype to the package.so its making me the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through object and eliminate objects which don't have value.

```
var myObject= {plotId: "668", geogPhysZone: "4", districtCode: "4", posMethod: "1", sRS: "45",crewLeader:"",date:"",distanceToOtherLanduse:"",distanceToSettlement:""};

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = myObject[key];
  if($.trim(val).length == 0){ //delete which are null or blank
    delete myObject[key];
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgbqjt51/)

Comment: but if i want to ignore the json key of only {plotId: "668"} then how can i ignore by key name?

Comment: you can put like - `if(key==="plotId")`